# how do I see a downvote

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've received a donwvote before but have no idea how to know who downvoted me.

I've also seen post where people have accused someone of downvoting them (and the accused acknowledged it).  How did the accuser know?

Comment: Reading the site rules and etiquette usually helps... a lot

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered reading the help section.

Comment: The accuser didn't know, they just guessed.

Answer (score 22):

Voting is anonymous. That's it. There is no direct way to find out who downvoted/upvoted your posts.

Now, with downvotes on *answers*, the caster gets -1 reputation, so there is a theoretical window of finding out who among the millions of our users got a -1 at the exact time you got the downvote on an answer, but with caching and latency (and the possibility that more than one person got a -1 at the same time), this isn't practical.

> How did the accuser know?

He doesn't. He is making accusations on pure guesswork and assumptions.

Comment: Why did you downvote the question if you're going to answer it? WHY?

Comment: ...and another Reversal badge on your dash! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It isn't like I am _trying_ to collect them.

Comment: @Oded yup, they just stick - but it's only showing you're doing your best to help even the most unpopular cases/requests. :)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot know who downvoted or upvoted you. Voting is secret. Sometimes if there is an argument between two people it happens that one of the two downvotes the other. It is easy to know in that case who downvoted you.

Maybe if you don't want to be downvoted you should not post these kind of questions. ;)

Comment: I've seen many cases where there's a disagreement but no downvotes related to it. It's certainly easier said than done, but I strongly suggest not making any assumptions about who voted how.

Answer (score -7):

It's entirely speculative, and some people assume (based on recent activity) that certain people have downvoted certain questions/answers.  Only Mods can actually see that information, and any "serial" downvoting (multiple downvotes on one person's activity by one specific person) will be adjusted and dealt with.

Comment: No, mods cannot see who voted on a certain post

Comment: How do they deal with/investigate serial downvoting, then, if they can't see the votes?

Comment: They're given tools that can identify *patterns* of suspicious voting. In extreme cases, they can escalate the problem to SE employees, who have access to the raw data if need-be.

Comment: Mods study linguistics, non-verbal communications and other language patterns as the culprits always out themselves

Comment: Also, serial voting (both up and down) is primarily handled by a script, not by humans. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/213634. As far as I know employees of SO (or at least the devs) can see and act on voting not caught by the script, but it is not my impression that it occurs frequently.